# MoPub Banner or Intersitial : Ad failed to load

Tags: android, ads, interstitial, mopub, banner-ads

I followed all MoPub's docs instructions, yet I am unable to display any MoPub banner or interstitial contacting support didn't help either.

I have the error message for intersitial or banner

```
07-06 20:57:12.465 14978-14978/? I/MoPub: Ad failed to load
07-06 20:57:16.415 14978-14978/? D/MoPub: No interstitial loading or loaded.
```

Build Gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'

compile('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:5.0.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

Manifest XML File permissions and dialogs

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

```
<!-- All ad formats -->
<activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

<!-- Interstitials -->
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

<!-- Rewarded Video and Rewarded Playables -->
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.RewardedMraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>


<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Initialization

```
    SdkConfiguration sdkConfiguration = new SdkConfiguration.Builder("myIDunit")
            .build();
    MoPub.initializeSdk(this, sdkConfiguration, new SdkInitializationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationFinished() {
       /* MoPub SDK initialized.
       Check if you should show the consent dialog here, and make your ad requests. */
        }
    });
```

Displays

```
mInterstitial = new MoPubInterstitial(getActivity(), "myID");
mInterstitial.load();
```

and then show()

Banner

```
moPubView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adView_reward);
moPubView.setAdUnitId("myID");
moPubView.loadAd();
```

Comment: have you added payment details

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you don't configure it wrong on the dashboard
2. don't make ad request before SDK finished initialization

btw, seems like you didn't add MoPubView to your layout XML files